# MLE is undefined for "densityless" distribution like Cantor distribution

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, density-function

I thought of a situation where we are given a random variable $X$ that has a Cantor "rescaled" distribution. That means that for a parameter $p>0$, $X$ has CDF $F_X(x)=C(\frac xp)$. This CDF has no derivative so $X$, a continuous RV, has no density. How do we define  the maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) in this case ? Since I feel the answer will be that we cannot define it, what tools do we have to estimate $p$ ? Here is the interesting part of $X$'s CDF for $p=1$.

[image]

Comment: For actually doing MLE, this doesn't matter, because you can always replace your random variables $X_i$ by $X_i+\epsilon Z_i$ where $Z_i$ are absolutely continuous *iid* variables, independent of the $X_i,$ supported on $[-1,1].$ In mathematics this process is called "mollification," where one would then consider the limit of the MLE as $\epsilon\to0.$